# TTFB Delays on Every Page Load

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, amazon-web-services, iis, orchardcms

This may very well be a question that is too broad to answer but any ideas would be incredibly beneficial.  I have a web site where load times are incredibly slow in one environment but not the other. In general, the time to first byte is around 15 seconds on most pages. It takes this long on every page within the entire application and not only on first load. I have been troubleshooting the issue for several days now and feel completely lost as to the actual cause for the latency.

[image: ttfb waiting time]

Now for a long explanation about the issue.

The environment is a Frankenstein monster of different sources where too many people have had their hands in it, from what I can gather. I have carefully taken the time to compare each of the two environments and haven't identified a key difference. There are numerous things at play here, but I can summarize the main components.

It is a .NET web application built using Orchard CMS running within IIS and has a SQL Server backend. A dedicated server hosts the database and the another dedicated server hosts the web application itself, which is pretty standard. The main difference between the environments is the production site is running in Liquid Web and the new development site is running in AWS. Basically, the site will ultimately be migrated to AWS once the latency issues are resolved.

AWS has more than enough resources. In fact, production (Liquid Web) has been running into issues as of late due to the CPU usage being nearly maxed out. There are many more resources in AWS, and neither of the servers appear to be using more than 1% or 2% of their available resources. I verified this.

If the issue is within the database, I'm not really sure where else to look. I used SQL Server Profiler on the database server to analyze traffic and no transactions were taking more than a half second, aside from the Audit Logins/Outs (which from my research is normal behavior). The main database queries execute almost immediately after trying to navigate to a page within the site, not 15 seconds later when the page loads.

I had a thought that the network traffic in AWS application server and the database server could be bottlenecked somewhere. However, resolving the application locally does not improve performance. I thought it could have been an issue with the routing within the domain, such as the way in which DNS is set up, but that does not seem to be the case either... or perhaps it is, and I just haven't figured out the best way to troubleshoot that. Either way, resolving the application on localhost does not improve performance. The page still hangs for 15-20 seconds.

[image: cpu usage on database server]
[image: cpu usage on web server]

The vRAM usage for the site's application pool and the default app pool certainly does seem on the high end, if that makes a difference.

[image: vram usage]

I have browsed the IIS logs and cannot find anything obvious. Granted, I don't have much experience in IIS and could be missing something. Windows Event logs show me nothing out of the ordinary either. There are some errors in both Liquid Web and AWS in regards to printer drivers not being installed, but those have nothing to do with the application itself.

[image: printer driver errors]

I am unsure of how to check if it has something to do with the Orchard CMS. Granted, this is just a package/framework that was migrated over into the dev server, directly along with the application itself. I see nothing that would have changed within the environment.

The fact is that the two environments seem identical, yet one is running very slowly based on some factor that I just can't seem to identify.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe this question is more suitable for https://serverfault.com? As it is not so much about programming as it is server issues?

Comment: I suggest you use [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html) to capture the network packages to explore more information anout this issue.

Comment: @samwu that was a good suggestion, and using that tool did help give some insight into one issue within the application (there was a slow connection being made to an external server). Unfortunately, that only improved performance from 18 seconds to 12-13 seconds.
It seems very likely the key issue is within the Orchard CMS, which is something that very few folks know much about. Either that, or our networking team just needs to admit that something isn't configured right on their end.

Comment: If it is caused by Orchard CMS, then you can get a [module for Orchard](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=orchardprofiler) to analyze it.